# How to calculate how many numbers $z$ of the form $z = p^2 + q^3$, where $p$ and $q$ are non-negative integers and $z < 50$, are there?

Tags: combinatorics

I was thinking in writing a table in which the left column represents the number that is going to be squared, and the right column has the numbers that can be powered to $3$ and added to the previous number squared in order to get the result.

$$0 -------> 0,1,2,3$$
$$1 -------> 0,1,2,3$$
$$2 -------> 0,1,2,3$$
$$3 -------> 0,1,2,3$$
$$4 -------> 0,1,2,3$$
$$5 -------> 0,1,2$$
$$6 -------> 0,1,2$$
$$7 -------> 0$$

Here we get $27$ possibilities, but then we have to substract the duplicities, that are four:

$$1 = 1^2 + 0^3 = 0^2 + 1^3$$
$$9 = 3^2 + 0^3 = 1^2 + 2^3$$
$$17 = 4^2 + 1^3 = 3^2 + 2^3$$
$$36 = 6^2 + 0^3 = 3^2 + 3^3$$

So, the result is $23$, but how could I get the numbers with an algorithm or process that examines each possibility only once?

Comment: "how could I get the numbers with an algorithm or process that examines each possibility only once?"  I would guess that you mean look through each of the 50 numbers from 1 to 50 one at a time and ask yes/no, is it of the form $p^2+q^3$? Whatever technique you would use to analyze a particular $n$ is likely to take some nontrivial computational effort, and then you will have to do that 50 times. Instead, what you outlined is a deterministic method that examines only 27 things. And I suspect all the arithmetic is less expensive the way you outlined it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the scope of this problem, brute-force is easy.

Try all $32$ pairs with $0 \leq p \leq 7$ and $0 \leq q \leq 3$ and check off the results $z$ as you go along. If you've checked off a particular $z$, you don't check it off again. And of course if the result is $\geq 50$ you don't check it off at all. (But you take this into account with your table, so you shouldn't have any $\geq 50$.)

Comment: Wouldn`t it be better to run throw all poosible values of p and check whether $z-p^2$ is a perfect cube ?

Comment: It seems quicker to loop over $q$ and check that $z - q^3$ is a perfect square, since there will be fewer values of $q$ to try before getting past $z$. Though I am not sure how fast the testing for perfect square will go.

Comment: @TobErnack : One could generate a lookUp table for the perfect squares.